# Реализация пошагового обновления GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, шаблоны-проектирования

Допустим необходимо реализовать следующую фичу. У меня есть GUI приложение со своей бизнес логикой. Модель довольно нетривиальная, и я хочу внедрить так называемый дебагинг. Другими словами, я хочу отслеживать изменение модели пошагово (например по нажатию клавиши F10). Хотел бы спросить, какое самое адекватное решение данной проблемы существует? 
На данный момент вижу два потенциальных решения:

1. Вынесение работы с моделью в отдельный поток (при включенном режиме
   отладки, после каждого оповещения об изменении, поток с моделью
   замирает, дабы gui могла обновиться, по нажатию f10 - поток
   просыпается)
2. Реализация на базе создания еще одного внутреннего цикла обработки
   сообщений (на каждом оповещении об изменении модели, мы создаем новый цикл посредством Dispatcher.PushFrame, и отключаем возможность изменения модели)

Не хочется городить велосипед, может уже существуют зарекомендовавшие себя подходы?

Comment: Если правильно вас понял, то это не "тестирование" а просто пошаговое выполнение. Не вижу проблемы реализовать это в виде дополнительной возможности (если хотите можете называть это режимом). Если говорить упрощенно то представьте задачу в виде списка последовательных операций где результат на каждой итерации не будет `принципиально` отличаться от конечного. То есть просто возвращайте переходное состояние таким образом наполняя список (конкретный тип данных будет зависеть от того дадите ли вы возможность перейти на шаг назад или только вперед)

Comment: @Foggy Finder, грубо говоря, хотите использовать аналог undo/redo списка? Если да, то не понятно, что именно должен хранить этот список - экшены, которые обновляют gui?

Comment: Нет, просто `состояния` . Было бы проще объяснить на примере. У вас есть возможность описать задачу более конкретно?

Comment: Ну например у меня есть дерево. Пусть оно отображает некоторое арифметическое действие. Изменяя значения узла. Изменяются связанные узлы. Как только модельное состояние узла меняется. Идет оповещение гуи.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, устоявшийся подход — отлаживать программу *по частям*.

Когда вы тестируете вашу модель, вам всё равно, есть ли у вас UI. Вы просто подаёте на вход значения, запускаете модель, и убеждаетесь, что она выдаёт нужный результат. (Возможно, это стоит автоматизировать в виде юнит-тестов.) И вы можете вполне смотреть значение ваших переменных в отладчике, UI вам для этого не нужен.

Когда вы тестируете бизнес-логику/VM, в простых случаях вы тоже можете просто пройти нужные куски под отладчиком, вам не нужно для этого UI. В сложных случаях (например, много асинхронные событий, на которые отладчик влияет не лучшим образом) заведите адекватный логгинг.

Для тестирования UI, проще всего разбить сложный UI на отдельные контролы (`UserControl`, `DataTemplate` и т. п.), и тестировать их по отдельности на тестовом приложении.

---

Если вы замечаете, что у вас для отладки бизнес-логики нужно дождаться реакции UI, у вас что-то неправильно в архитектуре: ваша бизнес-логика частично находится в UI-уровне! (Пример: у вас связаны две VM через `Binding` в UI. Это плохо и неправильно.) Убедитесь, что бизнес-логика бежит нужным образом и в отсутствие UI. Это ликвидирует проблемы с отладкой, и улучшит модульность вашего приложения.

Comment: Возможно я неправильно выразился.Я хочу реализовать тестирование модели посредством gui. Простой пример - мое приложение работает с визуальным представлением дерева. Что представляет дерево - не важно. Но, совершая какое-нибудь действие с узлом дерева, может измениться модель, мне хотелось бы увидеть, что происходит пошагово с деревом. Посмотреть все это через GUI.

Comment: Возможно слово тестирование здесь не совсем уместно. Просто такой вот аналог команды `step over`

Comment: @LmTinyToon: Тестирование модели посредством UI — это именно то, чего никто не делает. Модель обычно тестируют при помощи юнит-тестов: пишут код, который взаимодействует с моделью, и оценивает, насколько ответы от модели соответствуют ожидаемому поведению (то есть, ТЗ).

Comment: @LmTinyToon: То есть я не говорю, что так делать _нельзя_, может быть и можно. Но вы ведь спрашивали об общепринятых практиках?

Comment: Ну есть же программы которые используют подобный подход - например визуальные языки программирования (где дерево представляет собой программу, и можно тестировать это дерево через gui)

Comment: @LmTinyToon: Думаю, распространённость визуальных языков программирования является подсказкой к правильному ответу :-) Если серьёзно, там визуализацией выполнения занимается отладчик, специально для этого написанный, и бегущий вне контекста программы. WPF для такого не предназначен, и он не бежит отдельно. Вы можете попробовать пинками заставить его делать то, что вам нужно, но это всё равно будет хак и экзотика. Устоявшийся подход — тестирование модели без UI.